# Importing OpenStreetMap data into PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, postgis, openstreetmap, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to import one of the following OpenStreetMap maps [1](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11776689/2012_10_30_postgres/artyom.osm.bz2), [2](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11776689/2012_10_30_postgres/artyom.xml), [3](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11776689/2012_10_30_postgres/map.osm) into a PostgreSQL database using calls like `call osmosis.bat --read-xml file="map.osm" --write-pgsimp user="ccp-web-user" database="ccp-web2" password="ccp-web-password"`, but I always following error message.

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Thread for task 1-read-xml failed
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Unable to read the schema version from the schema info table.
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pgsimple.common.SchemaVersionValidator.validateDBVersion(SchemaVersionValidator.java:90)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pgsimple.common.SchemaVersionValidator.validateVersion(SchemaVersionValidator.java:50)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pgsimple.v0_6.PostgreSqlWriter.initialize(PostgreSqlWriter.java:183)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pgsimple.v0_6.PostgreSqlWriter.process(PostgreSqlWriter.java:773)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.xml.v0_6.impl.BoundsElementProcessor.end(BoundsElementProcessor.java:84)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.xml.v0_6.impl.OsmHandler.endElement(OsmHandler.java:107)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.xml.v0_6.XmlReader.run(XmlReader.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: Relation ╗schema_info½ existiert nicht Position: 21
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:254)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pgsimple.common.SchemaVersionValidator.validateDBVersion(SchemaVersionValidator.java:71)
        ... 19 more
30.10.2012 23:06:56 org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis main
SCHWERWIEGEND: Execution aborted.
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: One or more tasks failed
.
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.waitForCompletion(Pipeline.java:146)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.run(Osmosis.java:92)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.main(Osmosis.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: In the stack trace there is a message `Table schema_info doesn't exist`. I'm searching how to fix it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need initialize PostGIS simple schema as described [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage#PostGIS_Tasks_.28Simple_Schema.29).

> The schema creation scripts can be found in the scripts directory within the osmosis distribution.
>
> These scripts are:
>
> - pgsimple_schema_0.6.sql - Builds the minimal schema.
> - pgsimple_schema_0.6_action.sql - Adds the optional "action" table which allows derivative tables to be kept up to date when diffs are applied.
> - pgsimple_schema_0.6_bbox.sql - Adds the optional bbox column to the way table.
> - pgsimple_schema_0.6_linestring.sql - Adds the optional linestring column to the way table.
> - pgsimple_load_0.6.sql - A sample data load script suitable for loading the COPY files created by the --write-pgsimp-dump task.

If you are using PgAdmin3 open this files and execute them. Or use `psql` command. Of course PostGIS should be installed in your database.

Comment: I can't find these files in `PostgreSQL\9.2\share\contrib\postgis-2.0` directory. Does it mean that Osmosis fails because it expects another PostGIS version?

Comment: `pgsimple_*` files are located in `osmosis\scripts` directory. As I know osmosis works fine with PostGIS 2.0.

Comment: When loading `pgsimple_load_0.6.sql` in PgAdmin3, I get the error `[ERROR    ] 18.0: syntax error, unexpected character`.

Comment: I tried to run the command `call osmosis.bat --read-xml file="map.osm" --write-pgsimp user="ccp-web-user" database="ccp-gis-test" password="ccp-web-password" validateSchemaVersion="no"` again. Now I get a different error: `SCHWERWIEGEND: Thread for task 1-read-xml failed
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Unable to execute statement.
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pgsimple.common.DatabaseContext.executeStatement(DatabaseContext.java:159)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pgsimple.v0_6.impl.IndexManager.prepareForLoad(IndexManager.java:106)`

Comment: PgAdmin3 have special dialect called `pgScript`. It seems you're using it (`Query|Execute pgScript`) instead of plain SQL (`Query|Execute`). Try `Query|Execute` on clean PostGIS database.

Comment: If you wish, you could help me with this issue in scope of a paid project - http://www.vworker.com/RentACoder/misc/BidRequests/ShowBidRequest.asp?lngBidRequestId=1995124

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, and found a solution for myself on Ubuntu.

If you think you have already followed the steps on https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/PostGIS_Setup through psql commands, but still encounter errors, then there is possibility that there can be some issue with user permissions when executing psql commands on Linux terminal, such as when creating postgis and hstore extensions, and when executing pgsnapshot schema.

What I did:
- After creating a database on the terminal
- I used PgAdmin, go to the database (e.g. pgsnapshot) and execute the step of creating extension postgis and hstore. Then execute one of the schema creation scripts (e.g. pgsnapshot_schema_0.6.sql) inside that PgAdmin query tool. 
- After that, return to the terminal to execute commands (e.g.: osmosis --read-pbf ....)

These steps solved my issue.